# How to interpret each word in "so as to" separately?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, phrase-meaning, so-as-to

I already know the whole phrase *so as to* means *in order to*.
but still a bit curious about how to interpret each word in this phrase separately.

can I interpret the following sentence like this?

> He sat at the front so as to be able to hear. (quoted from cambridge dictionary)

where
*so* = in such way;

*as* = because of that;

*to*-clause is reduced from the clause with a modal auxiliary i.e. he *will/would* be able to hear,

*to* here is implying the meaning of mood auxiliary *will/would*.

put all together, the whole sentence can be interpreted like this:

> He sat at the front in such way because of that he would be able to
> hear.

not sure I get it right.

Comment: Try a different definition for ‘as’. It’s not “because” here it’s more like [def 8](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as)  *that the result is*

Comment: but "such that" also can be broken down to "such... because of that"? no?

Comment: You shouldn't try to interpret phrases by breaking them down into individual words. Think of the phrase as a single unit with a single meaning. There is no guarantee that you will find meanings of the individual components that correspond to the meaning of the phrase.

Comment: but why should not? I don't need anything to be guaranteed, if you don’t want to help, it’s okay for you not to reply

Comment: @StuartF: it is true that one should just 'think of the phrase as a single unit with a single meaning' **if** one is trying to understand the actual use of the phrase and learn to use it correctly. But that doesn't mean that it is misguided or improper to be curious about the relationship of its meaning to the meanings of its components. If one just wants to know the time, one should think of a clock as a single thing that tells time, but that doesn't mean that one shouldn't be curious about how its cogwheels, springs, etc. interact with each other